# Jackson deserializing hash map

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following JSON:

```
"propertyName": "{"1":[{"1":"value1","2":"value2","3":false}]}"
```

the first property being the count of items in the array following having a map of properties.

What is the best way to deserialize this using Jackson
if I want to fill up a class holding these values:

```
class MyHolder
{
   name = "value1";
   age = "value2";
   female = false;
}
```

for instance.

Comment: "Best" in what sense?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jackson: deserialization of Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362913/jackson-deserialization-of-map)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid. Let assume that JSON looks like this:

```
{
   "propertyName":{
      "1":[
         {
            "1":"value1",
            "2":"value2",
            "3":false
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

The simplest way is to create POJO classes which fit to your JSON. For example:

```
class Root {

    private Map<String, List<MyHolder>> propertyName;

    //getters,setters,toString
}

class MyHolder {

    @JsonProperty("1")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("2")
    private String age;
    @JsonProperty("3")
    private boolean female;

    //getters,setters,toString
}
```

Now we can easily deserialize it in this way:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{.. json ...}", Root.class));
```

Above program prints:

```
Root [propertyName={1=[MyHolder [name=value1, age=value2, female=false]]}]
```

If we do not want to see `Map` in our POJO class we have to write custom converter:

```
class MapMyHolderConverter implements Converter<Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>, List<MyHolder>> {

    @Override
    public JavaType getInputType(TypeFactory typeFactory) {
        return typeFactory.constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, List.class);
    }

    @Override
    public JavaType getOutputType(TypeFactory typeFactory) {
        return typeFactory.constructCollectionType(List.class, MyHolder.class);
    }

    @Override
    public List<MyHolder> convert(Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> map) {
        Collection<List<Map<String, Object>>> values = map.values();
        if (values.isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        List<MyHolder> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map<String, Object> item : values.iterator().next()) {
            MyHolder holder = new MyHolder();
            holder.setName(item.get("1").toString());
            holder.setAge(item.get("2").toString());
            holder.setFemale((Boolean) item.get("3"));
            result.add(holder);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Your POJO classes could look like this now:

```
class Root {

    @JsonDeserialize(converter = MapMyHolderConverter.class)
    private List<MyHolder> propertyName;

    //getters,setters,toString
}

class MyHolder {

    private String name;
    private String age;
    private boolean female;

    //getters,setters,toString
}
```

As you can see in second example we are using `@JsonDeserialize` annotation and we have not to use `@JsonProperty`.

Answer (score 6):

To deserialize to list/collection of concrete values (rather then the `LinkedHashMap` you get by default) you will need to pass type information to Jackson:

```
mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<MyHolder>>() { });
```

The other way to do the same is:

```
CollectionType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, MyHolder.class);
List<MyDto> asList = mapper.readValue(jsonString, javaType);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works great. For example to deserialize to a Map<String, JsonBean>:

`Map<String, JsonBean> myMap = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, JsonBean>>(){})`