# Deserialize POJO as a value in HashMap

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to deserialize a hashmap which values are sets/lists of objects. But Jackson does not recognize the class of these Objects.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(createTestData(1, 0));
System.out.println(json);
```

Which gives me:

```
{
   "interval":[
      {
         "discriminator":"Interval",
         "uuid":"298d8bc0-4259-4437-bd03-ffa83b62851c",
      }
   ]
}
```

Now, I want to deserialize it again:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
HashMap jsonWrapper = objectMapper.readValue(json, HashMap.class);
```

But `Jackson` creates my `Interval` object as a `HashMap`. I've configured `Interval` like that:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "discriminator")
public class Interval {
    ....
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're looking for this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431537/jackson-deserializing-hash-map/21432611#21432611. Cheers.

Comment: hm no, i have an map with sets as values, and the class of the objects is not predefined... it has to be determined while parsing, it should be determined by the @JsonTypeInfo

Comment: Could you create much complex example and show it? Now, I do not understand what are you trying to do and what is the difference between your question and question to which @Eugen gave URL.

Comment: What i need to deserialize is HashMap<String,Set<Interval>> but there can be Sets of other types, too